# Cordova: How launch external url?

Tags: cordova, webview

How to place an external url as webview so I run the app? I have already installed the cord, build, etc .. and also the inbrowserapp .. I do not know in which files put certain commands.

Comment: This is very broad. I would consider reading a `getting started` or beginners guide to cordova, as any answer to your question would be too long or opinionated, both of which are discouraged on this site.

Comment: Do you mean how to launch a URL from a Cordova app in the InAppBrowser or system browser, or how to launch a Cordova app from a URL that the user clicks in their device's standalone browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For launching an external website from your app

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {     
        openUrl();
        openPlayStore();
    }
    //for laaunching website
    function openUrl(){
       //opens inapp browser
        window.open("https://www.google.com/",'_self');
       //opens systen browser
        window.open("https://www.google.com/",'_system');
    }
  //open playstore app
   function openPlayStore() 
   {
      window.open(market://details?id=com.example.app','_system') 
   }
```